# Too much escaping?

Tags: php, wordpress, sanitization

I have a following code:

```
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( esc_attr( get_month_link( get_the_time('Y'), 
get_the_time('m') ) ) ); ?>"><?php the_time( get_option( 'date_format' )  ); ?></a>
```

My question is: am I doing to much unnecessary escaping because as you can see I am using
`esc_url()` combined with `esc_attr()`. Is this maybe an overkill? THX!!

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski let me be more clear: if it works then it's not doing "double encoding" (about that esc_url is safe but esc_attr is not) then he's not doing unnecessary encoding. Point should be if esc_attr is useful at all.

Comment: What are `esc_url` and `esc_attr`? User defined functions? If so, what do they do?

Comment: @MarcelKorpel they're WordPress functions.

Comment: Why not just use `htmlspecialchars`? What's wrong with that?

Comment: @MarcelKorpel because `escr_url` is specifically made to sanitize URLs, it's not just for escaping. _Problem_ IMO is if an URL returned from `get_month_link` needs to be sanitized (of course besides useless `esc_attr`)

Comment: How about, try removing esc_attr  and comparing the output to this version?

Comment: @DejoDekic to summarize little bit: IMO you do not need escaping made by `esc_attr` (because your URL won't contain characters it escapes) and `esc_url` is useless too (because I don't think URL returned from `get_month_year` has to be sanitized - it's not an user input).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarize little bit: IMO you do not need escaping made by `esc_attr` (because your URL won't contain [characters it escapes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_attr)) and `esc_url` is useless too (because I don't think [URL returned from `get_month_year`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_month_link) has to be sanitized - it's not an user input).

Then? Just remove them both:

```
<a href="<?php echo get_month_link( get_the_time('Y'), get_the_time('m') ); ?>"><?php the_time( get_option( 'date_format' )  ); ?></a>
```

Of course if you do not "trust" `get_month_year` parameters validation you can keep  `esc_url` (but let me say this may be little bit too paranoic).